# How to fire an event in asp.net when today changes to next day?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to fire an event (in asp.net with c#) when today changes to next day.

Comment: There are some different ways to create it, but in general, asp.net provides us something called `Background Worker`. It is going to run another thread in the background. You can schedule it to the time you need. See some implementations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795334/in-asp-net-core-3-1-how-can-i-schedule-a-background-task-cron-jobs-with-hoste

Comment: You looking on the backend or on the client?

Comment: Is this for `.NET Framework` or `.NET Core/5+`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer object.  Set the Timer to check every second, minute, or hour (as you see fit).  When the date changes, you can perform your processing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0

Answer (score -1):

use background worker,

You can implement using the following method,

1. Include System.Threading namespace.
2. Apply the threading code as follows,

Thread obj = new Thread(new ThreadStart());

obj.IsBackground = true;