# Fire Cron job automatically when application run .Net core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, hangfire

I have created a cron job in an API controller in .NET Core 6 as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/RunMyJob")]
public void RunMyJob()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => jobmethod(), Cron.DayInterval(5));
}

[NonAction]
public async Task jobmethod()
{
    // ........
}
```

I want to fire this job automatically when the project is run, without calling the API in the browser.

Comment: can any one help ?

Comment: so you want to schedule job on startup or you want to trigger job on startup ?.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official doc about [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

**Best code examples:**

[In ASP.NET Core 3.1, how can I schedule a background task (Cron Jobs) with hosted services for a specific date and time in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795334/in-asp-net-core-3-1-how-can-i-schedule-a-background-task-cron-jobs-with-hoste)